# How to parse Nested Json with python adjacent keys inside list

Tags: python, json, list, parsing

I am trying to parse this json and new in json.
Input

```
data ={'11': {'Des Content': ['Update Version', '11: Date of User'],
  'Date': ['920221207'],
  'service': ['courier']}}
```

```
keys=["11","21","13"]
```

Output

```
{
"11:":{
     "Describe" : "Date of User",
     "Data" :{
     "Date":["920221207"],
     "service":["courier"]
  }   
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Here I need to preprocess this input json and remove unnecessary keys to convert in desired output json.

Comment: How are you getting that output? It's neither the representation of a Python dictionary nor JSON. Also, the only key in the input data (which isn't JSON) is '11'. If you remove that you'll have an empty dictionary

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
res = {}
for k,v in data.items():
    res[k] = {"Describe": v.pop("Des Content")[-1].split(": ")[-1], # remove Des Content and assign Date of User to Describe
              "Data": v} # assign the remaining v dict to Data
res
# {'11': {'Describe': 'Date of User', 
#         'Data': {'Date': ['920221207'], 'service': ['courier']}}}
```